# Using CUDA8 in theano

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

I have working installtion of CUDA8 and have installed theano, while importing the theano it searches for CUDA7.5 instead of CUDA8, How can tell `theano` to use CUDA8 instead of CUDA7.5?

My sytem only have CUDA8, and it doesn't contain mixed environment cuda(i.e. having both CUDA7.5 and CUDA8).

Here is a output of `nvidia-smi`

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Feb  4 11:32:30 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P0    22W /  N/A |      0MiB /  3016MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
```

Here is a output of `nvcc -V`

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

While importing theano in ipython it fails to run in gpu mode with error that, it can't find the `libcudart.so.7.5`

```
Python 3.6.0 (default, Jan 16 2017, 12:12:55) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import theano
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)
```

Here is a content of my `.theanorc`

```
[global]                                                                                                                                                                                                       
floatX = float32
device = gpu0
cuda.root = /opt/cuda
```

I tried to build `theano` from source, after uninstalling the previous installtion of it, that too is not working. I did cleared the theano-cache with `theano-cache clean`/`theano-cache purge` and my manually deleting the content under `.theano` directory, which too couldn't helped.

With more debugging I get error here
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/8b9f73365e4932f1c005a0a37b907d28985fbc5f/theano/gof/cmodule.py#L302

when `nvcc_compiler` tries to load the `cuda_ndarray.so` from `cuda_ndarray` in theano cache

comiplation phase for mod.cu runs without error.

In this case linker is pointing to wrong `libcudart`

```
readelf -a cuda_ndarray.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcublas.so.8.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpython3.6m.so.1.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcudart.so.7.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

I assume `ldconfig` is properly caching the cuda libraries

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep -e 'cuda\|blas'
/opt/cuda/lib64:
    libcublas.so.8.0 -> libcublas.so.8.0.45
    libcudart.so.8.0 -> libcudart.so.8.0.44
    libnvblas.so.8.0 -> libnvblas.so.8.0.44
/opt/cuda/nvvm/lib64:
    libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.375.26
    libblas.so.3 -> libblas.so.3.7.0
    libicudata.so.58 -> libicudata.so.58.2
    libopenblas.so.0 -> libopenblas.so
    libicudata.so.58 -> libicudata.so.58.1
```

Comment: Might check the contents of .theanorc, but probably requires a recompile against sources?

Comment: I have checked it(http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html), but it seems that there is no option regarding it

Comment: Do you have anything in "config.cuda.root" in .theanorc?

Comment: yes @ColinBeckingham I tried with that, in my case `/opt/cuda` is my installtion directory.

Answer (score 0):

After more digging about the my issue, I refactored my original question and posted here [nvcc is picking wrong libcudart library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42127432/nvcc-is-picking-wrong-libcudart-library) which resolved my problem.