# nvcc is picking wrong libcudart library

Tags: cuda, linker, linker-errors, loader, nvcc

This problem comes when, I try to import theano with gpu mode. While importing the theano, it tries to compile some code, make a shared library of it and tries to load it.
Here is the command to make the so file.

```
nvcc -shared -O3 -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,\
  -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,-fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden -Xlinker \
  -rpath,/home/jay/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.8--ARCH-x86_64-with-arch-Arch-Linux--3.6.0-64/cuda_ndarray \
  -I/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Theano-0.9.0b1-py3.6.egg/theano/sandbox/cuda \
  -I/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy-1.13.0.dev0+72839c4-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include \
  -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Theano-0.9.0b1-py3.6.egg/theano/gof \
  -L/usr/lib -o /home/jay/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.8--ARCH-x86_64-with-arch-Arch-Linux--3.6.0-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.so \
   mod.cu -lcublas -lpython3.6m
```

It compiles the successfully but can't find the correct library for `cudart`.  The `ldconfig` seems to know the location of this library, which is correct.

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libcuda
    libcudart.so.8.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0
    libcudart.so (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
    libcuda.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcuda.so.1
    libcuda.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libcuda.so
```

But however when I inspect the library, it states the problem with `libcudart`.

```
$ ldd cuda_ndarray.so  | grep cuda
    libcublas.so.8.0 => /opt/cuda/lib64/libcublas.so.8.0 (0x00007f006dd1b000)
    libcudart.so.7.5 => not found
```

reading elf header

```
$ readelf -a cuda_ndarray.so | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcublas.so.8.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpython3.6m.so.1.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcudart.so.7.5]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

What went wrong so that it is picking the wrong library, `cudart7.5` instead of `cudart8.0` ?

here is a output of my `nvcc -V`

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

and my `libcudart.so` is pointing to correct library version

```
$ ls -la | grep libcudart
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        16 Jan 10 06:10 libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        19 Jan 10 06:10 libcudart.so.8.0 -> libcudart.so.8.0.44
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    415432 Jan 10 06:10 libcudart.so.8.0.44
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    775162 Jan 10 06:10 libcudart_static.a
```

and one more general question how does the linker resolves the actual file location of input like `-lm` or `-lcudart` or any shorthand notation used while compiling ?

I tried two of the sample programs shipped with cuda, which includes the `libcudart` library

```
$ grep -rnw . -e 'lcudart'
./3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile:329:LIBRARIES += -lcudart -lnvcuvid
./0_Simple/simpleMPI/Makefile:284:LIBRARIES += -L$(CUDA_PATH)/lib$(LIBSIZE) -lcudart
```

out of these two `simpleMPI` ran without error.

```
$ ./simpleMPI 
Running on 1 nodes
Average of square roots is: 0.667242
PASSED
```

The other one failed with earlier error

```
$ ./cudaDecodeGL 
./cudaDecodeGL: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You must have a broken CUDA installation somehow. What is the /opt/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so that you are linking? And what is the nvcc version you are using?

Comment: @talonmies I don't  think my CUDA installation is broken, to answer your questions I have amended my question.

Comment: So if you compile a cuda hello world from the command line, everything links and runs correctly? In that case there must be a dependency on CUDA be 7.5 in something you are compiling or linking in, like that Theano  stuff

Comment: how does the linker resolves the actual file location of input like -lm or -lcudart or any shorthand notation used while compiling ? do you have any good reference for it?

Comment: Your edit hasn't answered my question. Can you compile, link, and run a simple single source file CUDA program from the command line? If you cannot, then your CUDA installation is really broken somehow and you have a mixture of CUDA 7.5 and CUDA 8.0. If you can't answer that question, I can't help you.

Comment: I don't know much about CUDA, so instead of writing my own hello world program, I compiled sample program shipped by cuda, one is that simpleMPI and the other cudaDecodeGL. I thought that will be enough to check that sample programs given by CUDA compiles and run, do you still want me to compile hello world program? I can do that if tells us the some more amount of information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135268/discussion-between-bruce-wayne-and-talonmies).

Comment: I think the fact that the cudaDecodeGL sample when compiled on your machine fails in the same way (your nvcc version is clearly 8.0 but the compilation process is picking up a dependency on libcudart.so from CUDA 7.5) is a strong indicator that your CUDA install is broken.  You might have either CUDA tools like `nvcc` or CUDA libraries like libcudart that are scattered around on your machine (e.g. cuda is supposed to be in /usr/local/cuda, but you may have stuff in /opt or /usr/lib etc) and some sort of search path is picking up the wrong tools or libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the `CUDA8`, above the my old installation of `CUDA7.5`, so it moved old cuda libraries to `cuda/lib64/stubs`. After removing that directory everything worked as I expected.

Comment: so you did, in fact, have a broken CUDA installation.. please remember to come back in a few days to accept this answer sp it falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag

Comment: The installer doesn't move old cuda libraries to cuda/lib64/stubs.  That directory will be present even on a fresh install of CUDA 8 on a clean system, and deleting it means your CUDA 8 install is now broken for some tasks.

Comment: Thanks Robert for clarification. I haven't deleted that directory, but moved some-where else, I can move back that when necessary. This means my problem is not actually solved. Can you shed light on how `-lcudart` does get resolved, which we pass it to nvcc?